# NetLogo, how to hatch a turtle at a certain distance on Gis layers

Tags: gis, distance, netlogo

My patches contain attributes such as elevation :

```
set mnt gis:load-dataset "F:/StageM2/Modelisation/Modele/mnt.asc"
gis:apply-raster mnt alt
gis:set-transformation (list 567887.504252 573503.504252 6183200.86463 6187628.86463)  (list min-pxcor max-pxcor min-pycor max-pycor) 

gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of mnt
```

and turtles are created from raster of forest :

```
to import-foret93
set foret-93 gis:load-dataset "F:/StageM2/Modelisation/Modele/foret76_93.asc"
gis:apply-raster foret-93 f93
```

ask patches with [f93 = 1] 
   [
    set pcolor black
    set foret93? true
    ;ask n-of 2813 patches with [foret93? = true] [ hatch 2813 ]

```
sprout-arbres 1 [set color pink
  set size 4]
```

]
     end

The layers have the same spatial reference : RGF1993, so it is in meters.

Now, I want to create new turtles from existing turtles and randomly in a radius of 150m from the turtle (the new turtle can be hatch at 1m or at 130m). For instance, I ask just one turtle to hatch a turtle at a distance giving by an input box in the interface named dispersal-dist.

```
to disp-graines
ask turtle 2918
[
hatch-arbres 1
  [
  let seedX xcor
  let seedY ycor
  let ran-bear random 360
  lt ran-bear

 move-to one-of patches in-radius dispersal-dist

  set color magenta
  set size 15 
  ]
 ]

  end
```

But the created turtle go further then the dispersal distance giving in meters. 
Did I forget something to transforme the netlogo scale in meters ? Or it is another problem?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

While your raster dataset is expressed in meters in your case, your patches don't have a real world scale. Assuming your raster has square pixels, you can calculate a patch scale with something like:

```
let patch-scale (item 1 gis:world-envelope - item 0 gis:world-envelope ) / world-width
```

You could then use it in your existing code:

```
move-to one-of patches in-radius dispersal-dist / patch-scale
```

If your pixels in your raster have different real world height and width, you will have to do the patch-scale for the horizontal and vertical dimension separately.